# Need to loop through directory and all of it's subdirectories to find files at a certain in Perl

Tags: perl

I am attempting to loop through a directory and all of its sub-directories to see if the files within those directories are a certain size.  But I am not sure if the files in the @files array still contains the file size so I can compare the size( i.e. - size <= value_size ).  Can someone offer any guidance?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use DateTime;

my @files;
my $dt   = DateTime->now;  
my $date = $dt->ymd;
my $start_dir = "/apps/trinidad/archive/in/$date";


my $empty_file = 417;
find( \&wanted, $start_dir);
for my $file( @files )
{
  if(`ls -ltr | awk '{print $5}'`<= $empty_file)
  {
        print "The file $file appears to be empty please check within the    folder if this is empty"


  }
  else
  return;

}
exit;

sub wanted {
 push @files, $File::Find::name unless -d;
 return; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use this code instead of shelling out to awk.

(Don't understand why `my empty_file = 417;` is an empty file size).

```
if (-s $file <= $empty_file)
```

Also notice that you are missing an open and close brace for your `else` branch.

(Unsure why you want to '`return`' if the first file found that is not 'empty' branches to the `return` which doesn't do anything because `return` is only used to return from a function).

The `exit` is unnecessary and the `return` in the `wanted` function is unnessary.

**Update:** A [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) solution could be used. Here is a small program that captures all files less than 14 bytes in my current directory and all of it's subdirectories.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = '.';
my @files = find( file => size => "<14", in => $dir);
say -s $_, " $_" for @files;
```

Comment: Edited with a comma instead of the `=>`

Comment: Thanks Chris I didn't think about the -s for the checking of the size.  That does make it a lot more clearer!